# Imagem não atualiza após upload

Tags: flutter, upload

Estou fazendo uma aplicação usando Flutter, mas a imagem não atualiza na tela, mesmo depois dela ter sido salva corretamente. Veja os passos que sigo na programação.

**Passo 1**

Entro na página e ele carrega os dados da tela:

```dart
    bool _subindoImagem = false;
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
      _atualizaValoresIniciais(widget.redeModel);
    
      return Scaffold(...
    _subindoImagem
        ? CircularProgressIndicator()
        : FutureBuilder<RedeModel>(
      future: _atualizaImagem(widget.redeModel.id),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        ...
```

**Passo 2**

Clico em uma imagem para selecionar uma imagem na galeria:

```dart
    onTap: () {
      _showModalAtualizaImagem(context, "Imagem", "Buscar imagem de qual origem?", widget.redeModel.id);
    },

    A imagem é selecionada e no final do método "_showModalAtualizaImagem" faço o upload da imagem. Tudo funciona bem, pois a imagem gif do circular aparece enquanto se faz o upload e some ao finalizar.

    _imagem = _imagemSelecionada;
    if (_imagem != null) {
      setState(() {
        _subindoImagem = true;
      });
      _uploadImagem(idRede);
    }
```

**Passo 3**

Ao finalizar o upload e salvar a imagem corretamente, dentro do método "_uploadImagem" tento atualizar a imagem salva, sendo que neste ponto a imagem não aparece atualizada.

```dart
    Future<List<RedeModel>> _uploadImagem(int idRede) async {
      final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      String token = await prefs.getString(ConstantesConfig.PREFERENCES_TOKEN);
      var _url = "${ConstantesRest.URL_REDE}/${idRede}/imagem";
      var request = MultipartRequest();
    
      request.setUrl(_url);
      request.addFile("file", _imagem.path);
      request.addHeaders({
        //'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        'Authorization': token,
      });
    
      Response response = request.send();
      try {
        print(response);
      } on Exception catch (exception) {
        print(exception);
      } catch (error) {
        print(error);
      }
    
      response.onError = () {
        setState(() {
          _subindoImagem = false;
        });
      };
    
      response.onComplete = (response) {
        //_atualizaImagem(widget.redeModel.id);
        print("Buscar imagem via http");
        setState(() {
          _subindoImagem = false;
        });
      };
    
      response.progress.listen((int progress) {
        print("Buscar imagem via http");
        /*setState(() {
          _subindoImagem = true;
        });*/
      });
    }
```

Ao modificar a variável "_subindoImagem" para false, o método "_atualizaImagem" mostrado no primeiro bloco de código (lá em cima) é novamente chamado para atualizar a imagem na página.

Também tentei chamar o método "_atualizaImagem" dentro do response.onComplete, mas não gerou nenhum efeito na atualização da imagem em tela.

A imagem foi salva corretamente no servidor com o mesmo nome, ou seja, substituindo a imagem existente. Porém, o app insiste em mostrar a imagem antiga. Eu preciso fechar o aplicativo e entrar novamente, para que ele possa atualizar a imagem nova na página.

**Agradeço se puderes ajudar, pois já estou nisso um bom tempo, mas tudo o que tentei não obtive resultado para que a imagem possa ser exibida corretamente (atualizada).
Obrigado.**

Comment: O que a função _atualizaImagem faz?

Comment: Busca as informações executando um http via rest.
`_atualizaImagem(int idRede) async {
    RedeService redeService = RedeService();
    return redeService.buscaRedePorId(idRede, false); 
}`